# Working with focus and blur events on DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an `input type=text` control `T` that when focused runs some JavaScript to show a `div` UI element  `E`.

When `T` is blurred, `E` is hidden by an `onblur` callback.

But when the user clicks on `E`, `T` is of course blurred, but in this case I do not want to hide `E`.

How can I distinguish in the `onblur` callback for `T` between a normal blurring and a blurring to somewhere within the control?

I have tried `document.activeElement`, but this returns the `body` element which is of no use to me.

Minimum example:

https://jsfiddle.net/1w8hr5jr/

**Edit:**

Is it the case that because only certain kinds of DOM node can receive focus, that `focus` and `blur` are insufficiently powerful for my needs here?

Comment: Are you using JS pure only?

Comment: maybe you should not use onblur but a document click event to hide E, so you can test if the click target is or is not E or contained by E

Comment: Favour pure JS, but have JQuery

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @BenAston you havent found a way to achieve it with focus/blur events?

Comment: I decided to manage the state of the component manually myself using other events to inform the showing/hiding of the DOM node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion, as said in my comment, is to use a click event instead of blur and focus

html

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="foo"></input>
  <div id="bar">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var bar = document.getElementById('bar');

function onFocus() {
  bar.style.display = 'block';
}

function onClick(evt) {
  if (evt.target === foo) {
     bar.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (evt.target !== bar) {
     bar.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

container.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/she5fqmh/2/

I had the same challenge lately, and this is the best workaround I have found